# Why does argv have a 'v'

Tags: python, argv

I am studying Python as a novice programmer.  I have seen argv, as in sys.argv used and I believe it is used in other languages as well.  What is the significance of the 'v' in 'argv'? What does it stand for and where does the term originate?

I am hoping this will help me understand and remember the use of "argv".

Comment: Because the C version does of the variable does; see http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html for an explanation of the naming.

Comment: These date back to `C`, I believe. The `v` in `argv` is for argument 'vector' (and the accompanying `argc` was the argument 'count').

Comment: If my answer fulfill your need, you can accept it, if not, feel free to ask more about it :)

Comment: Thank you Thomas - this was my first question posted on StackOverflow and I did not realize the check mark was there for the clicking! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The variables are named `argc` (*argument count*) and `argv` (*argument **vector***) by convention, from C.

note that in Python there's no `sys.argc`. You just use `len(sys.argv)` as pointed [fred-larson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10077/fred-larson)

Comment: Python has no `sys.argc`, AFAIK. You just use `len(sys.argv)`.